# Node.js v4 migration (for sails.js or node.js)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am a sails.js user and I want to know what involves a migration for a previous version of node.js to v4 version : I know and read about new features like promises ,etc but I would know if even I could use features later, if my project could work or if there are things I'm forced to change?

For sails.js or a simple node.js project ( I don't know for sail.js , I saw no doc about this)

Comment: This question is too broad and unanswerable without knowing the intricacies of your application.  Try it out, run your test suite, and see what breaks.

Comment: You can already get the majority of the features of node4 (the es6 features) in the previous version via 3rd party modules such as babel, if that's the reason you were upgrading. Otherwise, you'll just have to try it and see if it works. You have a development environment, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not exact, because your question is to broad. I'll try to answer as objective as possible. The only way to answer is use it and see is there any feature that breaks. Maybe this points can help you:

1. Use test at your project, the more complex and broad test you defined, more accurate the result is.
2. Try to implement ES6 compiler at your project, if you already use Node.js that not supported ES6, use library like Babel, so you will know is your project will break or not is ES6 is implemented.

ES6 is backward compatible with ES5, so there are less things to worry about. And for your convenient, if you work on Linux based host, use Node.js version manager like `nvm`, so you will be easy to switch between any Node.js version.

Comment: Thanks Andi I made it yesterday : I upgraded to node v4. I had to upgrade gulp-sass unless my project wouldn't load. Now I have a problem with sails. When I use sails.models ['nameOfModel'] it doesn't create anything -> I'm trying to see where the error. I'm stuck right now. Another question I'm asking myself is if I understand for packages I have to ensure that they use Nan 2.x?

Comment: Personally I still recommend you to use node.js version below 4.x unless you want bring your project to bleeding edge, with very lack of community support and experience.

Comment: I think that's what I gonna do for my existing projects.